# Is volatile enough to check on a collection/map?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile

Let's suppose i have a collection or a map in a multi-threaded enviroment , and i have to execute certain operations based on if a value is in the Data Structure (the operations have nothing to do with the DS).
In my specific problem, **no variable can be removed once it has been added**.
Could i check this condition safely only by adding "volatile" to the DS?
What if removes were allowed?

Comment: Seems like you have a use case for a [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html). The `volatile` keyword only makes sure that the content of the variable is seen by all threads if it changes. But the variable content is the reference to your data structure (i.e. your map), not the map's values or keys.

Comment: For no variable can be removed once it has been added, you can check out Immutable map provided by Guava

Comment: You meed to be more specific about your problem.  We can't reason about whether using `volatile` will work without 1) seeing the proposed code and 2) knowing what properties the code needs to satisfy.  (I think that there *some* cases where you could use a `volatile` for this ... but I don't know if these use-cases match your use-case.)

Answer (score 0):

```
volatile Map<Object,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map = new HashMap<>();
```

changing map is visble to other thread

```
map.put("sth","sth");
```

changing the contents of the map is not immediately visible.

If you want change the contents of map,`volatile` is not enough. You can use `ConcurrentHashMap`,it has handled visibility in its internal implement, or you can use map and lock to ensure visibility.

Answer (score -1):

The `volatile` only ensures that changes to a variable are immediately visible to all threads (!), but it doesn't guarantee atomicity for compound operations, like adding or removing elements in a collection, so if you're trying to:

- **adding elements only**: using volatile can be kinda okay, ensuring the reference to the collection is up-to-date for all threads.
- **removing elements**: volatile is not enough. You need atomicity for operations like putIfAbsent or remove.

In both cases `volatile` does not protect the internal structure of the collection, so for complete thread safety you may consider using concurrent collections like `ConcurrentHashMap` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

Comment: The important point is volatile only makes changes to the *reference* visible - ie if you swapped out the (entire) map for a new map, all threads would see the new map the variable stores, but it does nothing whatsoever to make changes *inside* the map visible.

Comment: "[...] adding elements only: using volatile can be kinda okay [...]" No. I tried to explain (with my comment) that volatile only affects the variable's content which is the reference to the map. The map's content does nothing haver to do with it.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose said that volatile ensures that the content of a variable is  always updated and visible, so it shouldn't give any visibility guarantee on the content of the structure (as you stated at the end of the answer). Am i right or am i missing something?